# How to only stuff values from a unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I believe this is a very simple question with an equally simple answer, but I cannot figure this out.

I have a temporary table modeled like so and the query returns data like so:

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+--------+-----+
| Acct # | PO # | Store # | Order # | Line # | Ship Date | Item # | Qty |
+--------+------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+--------+-----+
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 |   1    | 11/23/16  | 100598 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 |   2    | 11/23/16  | 100597 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 |   3    | 11/23/16  | 100598 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 |   4    | 11/23/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 |   1    | 12/01/16  | 150962 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 |   3    | 12/01/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 |   4    | 12/01/16  | 150961 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 |   7    | 12/01/16  | 150961 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 |   8    | 12/01/16  | 156961 |  1  |
+--------+------+---------+---------+--------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

I am supposed to be consolidating like-rows together so that the Qty increases from 1 to 2, etc., for each item number that is the same on an order number. I have this part working but in order to do that I had to get rid of the line number, so the data returned looks like this:

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----+
| Acct # | PO # | Store # | Order # | Ship Date | Item # | Qty |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----+
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 11/23/16  | 100598 |  2  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 11/23/16  | 100597 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 11/23/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 12/01/16  | 150962 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 12/01/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 12/01/16  | 150961 |  3  |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

However, I need the Line # column to accurately report on which order-line is being worked on, shipped, etc. I know that the STUFF() function can do this except that it is adding every single Line # and not just the ones specific to the Order #. Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SupplierAcctNumber AS 'Acct #',
    BuyerPONumber AS 'PO #',
    BuyerStoreNumber AS 'Store #',
    SupplierOrderNumber AS 'Order #',
    SupplierOrderLine =
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(t.SupplierOrderLine AS VARCHAR)
            FROM @temp t
            WHERE t.SupplierOrderNumber = SupplierOrderNumber
                AND t.BuyerItemNumber = BuyerItemNumber FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,''),
    SupplierShipDate AS 'Ship Date',
    BuyerItemNumber AS 'Item #',
    SUM(SupplierQtyOrdered) AS 'Qty'
FROM @temp
GROUP BY SupplierAcctNumber, BuyerPONumber, BuyerStoreNumber, SupplierOrderNumber,
    SupplierOrderLine, SupplierShipDate, BuyerItemNumber
ORDER BY SupplierOrderNumber
```

And here are the results I got:

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
| Acct # | PO # | Store # | Order # | Line #            | Ship Date | Item # | Qty |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,7,8 | 11/23/16  | 100598 |  2  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,7,8 | 11/23/16  | 100597 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,7,8 | 11/23/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,7,8 | 12/01/16  | 150962 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,7,8 | 12/01/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 1,2,3,4,1,3,4,7,8 | 12/01/16  | 150961 |  3  |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

Here are the results that I expected:

```
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
| Acct # | PO # | Store # | Order # | Line #            | Ship Date | Item # | Qty |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 1,3               | 11/23/16  | 100598 |  2  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 2                 | 11/23/16  | 100597 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3340 |   648   | 1756013 | 4                 | 11/23/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 1                 | 12/01/16  | 150962 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 3                 | 12/01/16  | 100596 |  1  |
|  0777  | 3341 |   720   | 1760001 | 4,7,8             | 12/01/16  | 150961 |  3  |
+--------+------+---------+---------+-------------------+-----------+--------+-----+
```

Comment: You've got things mixed up. Your stuff statement should be `FROM @temp` with no table alias necessary, and your main query should have `FROM @temp t`

Comment: i think 150961 should be the item # in your last record not 156961

Comment: Woooow.... I can't believe I did not catch that. Thank you! Can you submit an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @scsimon you are correct. I just inserted dummy data and wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: @ZLK Can you post your answer so I can give you credit for figuring it out first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue, as mentioned in the comments, is a simple mixup with how the STUFF was written. Adjusted, the query should looke like this, with the table alias for @temp outside the stuff statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    SupplierAcctNumber AS 'Acct #',
    BuyerPONumber AS 'PO #',
    BuyerStoreNumber AS 'Store #',
    SupplierOrderNumber AS 'Order #',
    SupplierOrderLine =
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(t.SupplierOrderLine AS VARCHAR)
            FROM @temp
            WHERE t.SupplierOrderNumber = SupplierOrderNumber
                AND t.BuyerItemNumber = BuyerItemNumber FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,''),
    SupplierShipDate AS 'Ship Date',
    BuyerItemNumber AS 'Item #',
    SUM(SupplierQtyOrdered) AS 'Qty'
FROM @temp t
GROUP BY SupplierAcctNumber, BuyerPONumber, BuyerStoreNumber, SupplierOrderNumber,
    SupplierOrderLine, SupplierShipDate, BuyerItemNumber
ORDER BY SupplierOrderNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. I'm sure there are better... but for your structure it'll work.
Also,  think 150961 should be the item # in your last record not 156961

```
select
    [Acct #],
    [PO #],
    [Store #],
    [Order #],
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cast([Line #] as varchar) from #tt where [Order #] = t.[Order #] and [Item #] = t.[Item #] FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') as [Line #],
    [Ship Date],
    [Item #],
    SUM(Qty) as Qty
from #tt t
group by 
    [Acct #],
    [PO #],
    [Store #],
    [Order #],
    [Ship Date],
    [Item #]
```